# MP3 not playing in FBML

Tags: audio, mp3, fbml, facebook-fbml

Our application is dead, I'm using FBML mp3 tag for audio loading

```
<fb:mp3 src="http://musicurl.mp3" title="title" artist="artist" album="album"/>
```

The app is used for more than 100k users and it worked properly, but suddenly, the player can't get and play the mp3 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio player hasn't worked in 2 days.

See related posts:

- http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165246693563413
- http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F7662361%2Ffacebook-audio-player-broken&h=8AQD4mVIgAQAFUXS-lLPJaLUFwabDLy30WTAleUkWmRyQHg